# Why is the performance of this looping CLI code not significantly faster than C# managed code?

Tags: c#, performance, for-loop, c++-cli

When I comment out the bulk of the code below and uncomment the SpeedCreateImageMap2D() line which calls the CLI code, the stopwatch timing is virtually identical (~5ms for both).

I expected the CLI code to be much (e.g., 5x-10x) faster than the managed C# as I have experienced on other similar kinds of looping functions in the past, but it wasn't.

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE1: Made example minimum/complete/verifiable by replacing top section of code.**

```
int width = 640;
int height = 512;
int numPixels = width * height;
ushort[] imageData = new ushort[numPixels];
for (int i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) {
    imageData[i] = (ushort)randomGenerator.Next(4095);
}

Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// Create and populate a 2D pixel map
int rowNum, colNum;
ushort[,] pixelMap2D = new ushort[width, height];
for (int i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) {
    rowNum = i / width;
    colNum = i % width;
    pixelMap2D[colNum, rowNum] = imageData[i];
}
//ushort[,] pixelMap2D = SpeedCode.SpeedClass.SpeedCreateImageMap2D(imageData, width, height);
Debug.WriteLine("Speed(ms): " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("N2"));
```

CLI function:

```
array<UInt16, 2> ^ SpeedClass::SpeedCreateImageMap2D(array<UInt16> ^imageData, int width, int height)
{
    // Create and populate a 2D image map from a 1D array of image data
    array<UInt16, 2> ^imageMap2D = gcnew array<UInt16, 2>(width, height);
    int rowNum, colNum;
    int numpixels = width * height;

    for (int i = 0; i < numpixels; i++)
    {
        rowNum = i / width;
        colNum = i % width;
        imageMap2D[colNum, rowNum] = imageData[i];
    }
    return imageMap2D;
}
```

**UPDATE2: Changing the CLI code to a nested for loop per the suggestion improved performance by ~2X but the corresponding managed code performance also improved by ~2X.  If there is an even faster way to do this, please let me know.**

```
    array<UInt16, 2> ^ SpeedClass::SpeedCreateImageMap2D(array<UInt16> ^imageData, int width, int height)
{
    // Create and populate a 2D image map from a 1D array of image data
    array<UInt16, 2> ^imageMap2D = gcnew array<UInt16, 2>(width, height);
    int k =0;
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            imageMap2D[i, j] = imageData[k];
            k++;
        }
    }
    return imageMap2D;
}
```

Comment: Both are compiled to IL, and then JITted to native code at runtime. Assuming they compile to substantially the same IL, why should the performance be significantly different? Note that without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's not possible to even verify that you are measuring the performance correctly, never mind offer an explanation for the performance you observe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programmers tend to overlook their most effective optimizer available, the one between their ears.  You are making several mistakes:

- Multi-dimensional arrays in .NET are pretty inefficient.  Indexing them is slow, it requires multiplying by the lower dimension size and there are *rank* number of bounds-checks for ever element access.  Jagged arrays are *much* better, simple indexing with just a pointer+size calculation and just a single bounds-check.
- Your code is addressing the array in a very cache-unfriendly order.  Locality of reference is very important on modern processors, you always want to address memory in storage order.
- The C++/CLI compiler generates MSIL for code that is compiled with /clr in effect.  Even pure native C++ code (this is not), you still depend on the jitter to generate and optimize the machine code.  There is no difference whatsoever with the kind of MSIL generated by the C# compiler here.  Which is why you could not observe any difference.
- Writing native code that's faster than what the jitter can do isn't that easy.  You are typically only ahead when you make code unsafe intentionally, bypassing array index bounds checking for example.  But very difficult to make that pay off on code like this, the real throttle here is the memory bus.  A large array that won't fit in the processor caches causes too many stalls, nothing you can do about it but upgrade your hardware.

Another version of the same code with these bullet points in mind:

```
static array<array<UInt16>^>^ CreateImageMap2D(array<UInt16>^ imageData, int width, int height) {
    // Create and populate a 2D image map from a 1D array of image data
    auto imageMap2D = gcnew array<array<UInt16>^>(height);
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        imageMap2D[i] = gcnew array<UInt16>(width);
        Array::Copy(imageData, k, imageMap2D[i], 0, width);
        k += width;
    }
    return imageMap2D;
}
```

I didn't measure it but you should be well ahead by the better cache utilization.  Further optimizing this code is very unlikely to pay off, you need to beat Array::Copy().  It is already optimized.  But you can try with `pin_ptr<>` to pin the arrays and memcpy() to copy the data.  Writing this in C# won't make any difference, probably what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions and the example code.  After implementing your suggestion, I took it even further and ended up reconfiguring my code to use a flattened array instead of a 2D array and got the best performance from that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Both C# and managed C++ compile to IL and than JITed at runt time. As result overhead for both versions is about the same and code itself is likely compiled into very similar IL - so no significant difference in speed should be expected.

You will get faster startup from regular C++/C code (no JIT required) and less support libraries.

You *may* get slightly better performance of the code itself using C++/C due to better optimizations, but your code is very simple and likely produce nearly optimal native code via regular JIT of C#-generated code. Or native code could be slower due to different tradeoff for memory mangement (managed code get almost no-time allocation and relatively expensive de-allocation, while native code generally splits cost about equally).

Answer (score 0):

> I expected the CLI code to be much (e.g., 5x-10x) faster than the managed C# as I have experienced on other similar kinds of looping functions in the past

This is extremely workload dependent. It also is dependent on whether you make VC++ compile the code to IL or to native code.

Here, I would guess that the **division and modulus** dominate performance. While other primitive operations such as `+-&|^` are very fast (like 1 CPU cycle latency) division is really expensive (15-30 cycles even on modern CPUs). These operations dominate throughput. Everything else does not matter much. (Fun fact: Hash tables using `%` to calculate the bucket are very measurably slower than alternatives! This operation is really slow.).

Find a better way to calculate `rowNum` and `colNum`. Two nested loops are a common way to do that.

Comment: Your comment about division and modulus dominating the performance was probably correct.  Thanks!

Comment: I was a bit premature on marking this as the answer.  While the performance improved by ~2X in the CLI case, it improved by the same amount in the managed case as well.  I'm glad it improved, but still puzzled why the CLI is not faster than managed.  CLR Support is listed as "/clr"...is that what you mean by compiling the code to native code vs. IL?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with C++/CLI. I always controlled native code gen using a pragma. That way you can switch individual method between IL and x86.

Comment: How do you do it with your pragma method?

Comment: I don't remember. Use a search engine. "C++ CLI native code pragma"

Comment: I found #pragma managed(push, off) and #pragma managed(pop), but when I add them around the function, I get all sorts of errors about managed functions.  I must be using some managed types.

Comment: Yeah, but those a are the correct pragmas. Sometimes you need to create a managed wrapper/adapter to comply with requirements.